# How can I do a simple asynchronous query implementation in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

Is there a simple tutorial for this somewhere?

Ideally I'd like to have a textbox and a button, and when the user clicks the button, the textbox is sent to the server, which returns a value based on it.

The client then populates another textbox with the return value, but all without refreshing the page.

If it's possible, showing/hiding a loading gif would be awesome too.

I'm not finding any simple tutorials for how to do this, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try googling for jQuery+AJAX.

There are lots of examples out there:

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/
- http://visionmasterdesigns.com/tutorial-ajax-interface-menu-using-jqueryphp/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ajaxjquery.html
- http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development.html

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's Ajax method is your friend: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm" action="/echo/html/" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <textarea name="html" class="firstInput"></textarea>
        <textarea class="secondInput"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="GO!">
    </fieldset>
</form>

<img src="http://vinofordinner.com/art/loading.gif" id="loader" />
```

**CSS**

```
#loader {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this),
            data = $this.find('.firstInput').serialize(),
            method = $this.attr('method'),
            action = $this.attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: action,
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loader').show();
            },
            success: function(a){
                $('.firstInput').val('');
                    $('.secondInput').val(a);
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loader').hide();
            }
        });
    })

})
```

***Working example:***  http://jsfiddle.net/G4uw6/

Comment: I guess no one left you a comment thanking you for this, I'm learning jquery, and I have learned a lot from your code, so thank you

Answer (score 1):

You would do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'handlerscript.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {q: $('#theInput').val()},
    success: function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
        alert('Load was performed.');
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('.loadgif').show();
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('.loadgif').hide();
    }
});
```

To walk you through the function, the first parameter `url` is set to the **location** of the resource you want to get a response from. The `type` parameter sets the **HTTP method** used, it is most commonly set to either `GET` (which is the default value) which appends any data being sent **to the url** or `POST` which appends any data being sent **to the request header**. `data` is an object or string containing the data to be sent to the requested page, it can either be in object form `{param1: 'value1',param2: 'value2'}` or as url encoded string `"param1=value1&param2=value2"`. The `success` method is called when a response has been received from the server which was **successful**. The `beforeSend` method is called before the request is sent and the `complete` method is called when a response has been received from the server **regardless of the success of the request**.

For more info, check out the [Official jQuery API documentation of the jQuery.ajax() object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)