# Update value in ListView

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, listview

I have a button inside a listview and a label. The label is bound to my database and displays a score. If you press the button I want the score to update on client side. But Since I cant access items in Listview from codebehind I have no idea how to do this. And updatepanel does not work.

My listview bound to a Sqldatasource:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewSearch" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceWebsite" DataKeyNames="WebsiteID">
```

My buttons and my label for rating:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="BtnUp" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("testId").ToString() %>' OnClick="up_click"></asp:LinkButton>

<asp:LinkButton ID="BtnDown" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("testId").ToString() %>' OnCommand="down_click"></asp:LinkButton>

<asp:Label ID="LabelRating" runat="server" Text=' <%# Eval("rating") %>'></asp:Label>
```

upClick() function:

```
protected void up_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
            String webID = btn.CommandArgument.ToString();
            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(webID);
            click(ID, 1);
        }
```

Click() function:

```
public void click(int webID, int vote)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Test] SET [rating]+=@vote WHERE [testId]=@testID";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@webID", webID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vote", vote);

                    con.Open();

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

The code updates the rating as it is supposed to, but to see the change I have to refresh the page. So the questions is; How do I update a value inside a listview by clicking a button inside that same lisview?

(If this is not possible, please suggest a different way that I can display results from a search in a list that offers the same customization.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm more into ASP MVC however maybe my tip will help you. 
The way I did these behaviors was to bind javascript function to the button and using jQuery I've send 'GET' request to the specific action(method) on the server for example: www.myexample.com/getData?tableid=24 which responds with json containing needed data.
Hope this will direct you to proper solution.

Cheers,
Marek

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I might be able to do this. What does tableid represent? And does this method not refresh the entire page?

Comment: Inside your listview you have id of a data binded to given cell you want to refresh. So in your request you have to pass this id in order to lookup your database for needed data. When your jQuery request is finished you just have to replace content of the control with the new data. It won't cause whole page to be refreshed. Here is another topic which covers jQuery async requests samples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767653/how-can-i-do-a-simple-asynchronous-query-implementation-in-jquery

Comment: Ah, but how do I know which id it is since Im filling it from database? You dont have any sample code? Im fairly poor at jQuery